# If $A$ is independent of $B$ and we have $C\subset A$. Then $C$ is also independent of $B$.

Tags: probability

Let $A,B,C$ events. If $A$ is independent of $B$ and we have $C\subset A$. Then $C$ is also independent of $B$. Intuitively this seems obvious but how do you prove this? Or is is the statement even true?

Comment: It's not true.  Suppose you are throwing a fair die and let $A$ be the event "an even number is tossed", $B$ the event "either $1$ or $2$ is tossed" and $C$ the event "$4$ is tossed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments:  the desired claim is false.

Here is a simple counterexample.  Say we are tossing a fair die.

Let $A$ be the event:  "an even number is tossed".

Let $B$ be the event:  "either $1$ or $2$ is tossed".

Let $C$ be the event:  "$4$ is tossed."

Obviously $C\subset A$.

To see that $A$ and $B$ are independent we remark that $A\cap B$ is the event "$2$ is tossed" so that $P(A\cap B)=\frac 16$.  On the other hand, $P(A)\times P(B)=\frac 12\times \frac 13=\frac 16$ as desired.

But $C$ and $B$ are not independent, indeed they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is probably not true.

$$P(B) P(A)=P(B\cap A)= P((B\setminus C)\cap A) +P(C\cap A)$$

Since $P(B) = P(C) + P(B\setminus C)$ we have $$P(C)P(A) + P(B\setminus C)P(A)=  P((B\setminus C)\cap A) +P(C\cap A)$$

So $$P(C)P(A) = P(C\cap A) \iff P(B\setminus C)P(A)=  P((B\setminus C)\cap A)$$

i.e. $A$ and $C$ are independent iff $B\setminus C$ and $A$ are independent.