# If $A$, $B$ are both pairwise independent of $C$, do we have that $A \cap B$ is also independent of $C$?

Tags: probability

If $A$, $B$ are both pairwise independent of $C$, do we have that $A \cap B$ is also independent of $C$?

Comment: Independent of $B$ or of $C$?

Comment: What have you tried?  Between this and [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678317/if-a-is-independent-of-b-and-we-have-c-subset-a-then-c-is-also-independ) it looks like you are just posting your homework here for us to do for you.

Comment: @saulspatz I mean that we have $P(A \cap C)=P(A)P(C)$ and $P(B\cap C)=P(B)P(C)$

Comment: @lulu No it's not homework I was just wondering about in my head and thought I would ask it on stack exchange.

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking about the very last letter in the question.

Comment: @lulu your previous answer was much appreciated by the way :)

Comment: changed it, that was a typo it should be C.

Comment: Keep_On_Cruising  Please understand that your question is posed in a manner that homework questions are posed.  And if it is not homework, or if it is, doesn't matter.  In either case, we expect *context* from the asker.  Where did you encounter this problem? (Source?)  Where are you stuck (specifically, describe where in your own work are you stuck?)  What relevant definitions or equations might apply?  Homework questions are not banned, but posting questions that are merely transcribed from homework-type questions is not acceptable.  Please edit your post to include such context.

Comment: Context... it's just an easy to state question? What more context do you need? And source? This is just a site to ask math questions not a site where you publish scientific results. Take it easy man.

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising And that's where you are wrong. There are rules to follow to use the site, and you are blatantly ignoring them. And, you respond to amWhy alerting you to the violation of these rules with condescension. That's pretty poor.

Comment: @DonThousand Not with condescension, but I can defend myself right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toss two fair coins.  Let $A$ = "first toss heads", $B$= "second toss heads, $C$ = "first same as second".

Comment: Don't know why this received a downvote. It is a valid counterexample. (Perhaps it's because this is a PSQ)